# Can a puppet resource reference one of its own attributes?

Tags: puppet

I have an `Exec` resource that starts a process with some specific flags/parameters. I don't want it to run if the exact process is already running. I thought I could reference the resource's own `$command` attribute. But, that doesn't really work... **is there some way to reference the current resource?**

```
exec { 'foo':
  command => 'foo --bar baz',
  unless  => "pgrep -f '${command}'",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way for a resource to reference it's own attributes. You could, at least, extract the command to a variable within the appropriate scope.

```
$foo_bar = 'foo --bar baz'

exec { 'foo':
  command => $foo_bar,
  unless  => "pgrep -f '${foo_bar}'",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. There is not.

You can (and should) solve this by wrapping `exec` in a defined type.

```
define safe_exec($command=$name, $parameters = "") {
    exec {
        "$command $parameters":
            unless => "pgrep -f '$command'",
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "should"? Is there something in the style guide or best-practices?

Comment: No, but this is *the* language construct for distributing a value to multiple new resources, or multiple attribute values of the same resource.